# Hide the scrollbar of a ScrollView when there is no overflow in Android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview

Is there a way to hide the scrolling features(scrollbar, top and bottom effects) of a ScrollView if there is no overflow, but the user still drags the view?

Answer (score 0):

Disable scrolling on the ScrollView (since its not needed)

Here's an example:

[How to disable ScrollView scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652692/how-to-disable-scrollview-scrolling)

Even though that does seem like a lot of work. Maybe you could just layer a transparent view on top of the scrollView to block the touches (I've done something like this in the past)

Comment: I only want it to be disabled when there is no overflow though.

Comment: Hmmm...if that's the case where sometimes there's scrolling and sometimes there's not then I would just leave the default behavior as is. That's the way Google intended it.