# Android touchable items in scrollview

Tags: android, events, touch, scrollview

I have an array of imageViews inside a linearlayout inside a scrollivew.
The imageviews have onTouchEvent and get DOWN touch event when scrolling.
I need a method so I can scroll without the views intercepting DOWN event.

Child touch listener

```
image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    int action = event.getAction();

                    switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        Animation scale = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0.5f, 1f, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                        scale.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                        scale.setFillEnabled(true);
                        scale.setFillBefore(true);
                        scale.setFillAfter(true);
                        scale.setDuration(300);
                        v.startAnimation(scale);
                        image.getParent().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        image.getParent().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        scale = new ScaleAnimation(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                        scale.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
                        scale.setFillEnabled(true);
                        scale.setFillBefore(true);
                        scale.setFillAfter(true);

                        scale.setDuration(200);

                        scale.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                toggle();

                            }
                        });

                        image.startAnimation(scale);
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(image.getId(), false);
                        v.performClick();

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        scale = new ScaleAnimation(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                        scale.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
                        scale.setFillEnabled(true);
                        scale.setFillBefore(true);
                        scale.setFillAfter(true);

                        scale.setDuration(200);

                        scale.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                toggle();

                            }
                        });

                        image.startAnimation(scale);
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(image.getId(), false);
                        v.performClick();
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: have you tried setting `duplicateParentState` flag to false? [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDuplicateParentStateEnabled%28boolean%29)

Comment: It does nothing, I need my scrollview to intercept only move action. children only down and up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every "set of actions" starts from `ACTION_DOWN`, so your `ImageView`s will get this action always, because they can handle it (state change). but `ACTION_MOVE` can be handled only by `ScrollView` so these `TouchEvent`s are passed forum Button-child (dispatched) to ScrollView-parent (through LinearLayout).

you can use dispatching and intercepting `TouchEvent`s ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586032/android-difference-between-onintercepttouchevent-and-dispatchtouchevent)) with passing your action type to proper `View`

but... how do you know what user wants? in the exact moment of touch (`ACTION_DOWN`) user might want to scroll OR click button, so you don't know how/to who dispatch later events and how views have to behave. I see in your code that you want animate your button - better try with its states and start animation with `state_pressed` changed to `true` and reverse it when set `false`. BUT its probably give you same effect. another way is to hold whole `ScrollView` when button got hit ([some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652692/how-to-disable-scrollview-scrolling)), but its poor solution in the terms of UX

check out some apps in Google Play or even Google Play app itself. Press any clickable View/App on any list - it changes background, on Lollipop some ripple effects etc.... but when you scroll the whole view pressed View/App lose these effects (`state_pressed` to false). There is no way you can guess what user want to do at the moment of `ACTION_DOWN`, so above described effects (losing) are normal

EDIT:
as I said - there is no way and proper behaviour for guessing what user wants to do (click/scroll) at moment of `ACTION_DOWN`, so your code and use is fine. almost...

here is an example of one of my (really old) custom views called Arrow (it contains arrow ;) )

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")  //Honeycomb ofc, use NineOldAndroid for older
public class Arrow extends ImageView implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener{

    ValueAnimator va_scaleX=null, va_scaleY=null;

    public Arrow(Context context) {
        super(context);
        createAnimation();
    }

    public Arrow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        createAnimation();
    }

    public Arrow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        createAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        invalidate();
    }

    private void createAnimation() {
        if (va_scaleX == null || va_scaleY==null) {
            va_scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleX", 0.5f);
            va_scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleY", 0.5f);
            /* useful, optional, similar methods from Animation
            va_scaleX.setDuration(150);
            va_scaleY.setDuration(150);
            va_scaleX.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            va_scaleY.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());*/

            va_scaleY.addUpdateListener(this); //one is enough
        }
    }

    public void startAnimation() {
        va_scaleX.start();
        va_scaleY.start();
    }

    public void reverseAnimation() {
        va_scaleX.reverse();
        va_scaleY.reverse();
    }
}
```

its not the best way (two animators), but works like a charm.. note that while animating this View drawable states wont be refreshed (eg. when you set `selector` as a background). usage of `ValueAnimator` instead of regular `Animation`

```
arrow.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        a.startAnimation();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        a.reverseAnimation();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

it creates smooth reverse animation, so when user press Arrow (`ACTION_DOWN`) animation will start, but also when next action isn't for this view (`ACTION_MOVE` in this case) the `reverseAnimation()` method will be called which return this View to original size. whole operation will be pretty fast, so user won't even notice this small resizing (and reversing)

Comment: Ok, I understand the part with action down not being a good approach, what way would you suggest to have an animated menu that is in scrollview.
The imageview just goes down on click and overshoots when released.