# Closing items in SwipeMenuListView

Tags: listview, swipe, menuitem

I use com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView in linearLayout and scrollView because I need more lists on one screen. When user is swiping item and scroll whole screen together, it doesnt close, and it is still open, like on picture below. I dont know how to force close it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solve it just for opening with scrollview from Asha Soman answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652692/how-to-disable-scrollview-scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWwnX.png)

```
listGroupsToUpload.setOnSwipeListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnSwipeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSwipeStart(int position) {
        LOG.print("onSwipeStart");
        scrollView.setScrollingEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipeEnd(int position) {
        LOG.print("onSwipeEnd");
        scrollView.setScrollingEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

but I realise, that I will need to detect, when user start closing. So I modified library (class SwipeMenuListView) a little and I added two custom onPress listener like on picture below (do not forget check them for null) and one release listener for ACTION_UP and now it is working.

[image]

```
listGroupsToUpload.setOnReleaseListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnReleaseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPress() {
        scrollView.setScrollingEnabled(false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRelease() {
        scrollView.setScrollingEnabled(true);
    }
});
```