# Disabling scroll in Signature view issue

Tags: android, custom-scrolling

I am trying to add view for signature in scroll view,So i have disabled scroll view when we start signature gesture on signature view and it's working fine. But i am trying to enable the scroll on parent layout onTouchlistner. But due to other views,scroll is not working properly .
I tried the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652692/how-to-disable-scrollview-scrolling),but unable to solve my issue.

This is to disable scollview on gesture  touchlistner

```
    digitalSignView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       //The following code is to disable  scroll view on gesture touchListener.
            ScView.setEnableScrolling(false);
            return false;
        }});

    parentLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           //The following code is to enable parent scroll view on outside touch event.
            ScView.setEnableScrolling(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Please help me how to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.